# Passing a List of values and rerturning a Dictionary for their associated results

Tags: c#, linq

In My table I have some columns, two of them in my interest:
`Description` and the `Key` column
so some sample rows will look like this:

```
Key    Description 
12RRR  "Description 1"
45RTG  "Description 2"
45ERT  "Description 3"
```

I want to write a method that gets a list of `Descriptions` and returns me another list or dictionary or any other appropriate structure that is the `Key` value for that `Description`. 
I can write a simpler query to search one by one. Pass one description, get its Key,etc... but my list is about 120,000 items so that way I will be running the script for 120,000 times! That's why I want to pass them all and get them all in one query.

That's how far I got but I don't think this is correct.

```
private List<string> Lookup(List<string> des)
{
    var query = (from r in repo.Context.MyTable
        where des.Contains(r.Description)
        select r.Key);
    return query.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what structure you're asking for but if you want a lookup of Key to Dictionary, you can create such a dictionary using LINQ's [ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.95).aspx) on the result.

```
private IDictionary<string, string> Lookup(List<string> des)
{
    var query = (from r in repo.Context.MyTable
        where des.Contains(r.Description)
        select r);
    return query.ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.Description);
}
```

Comment: Looks like that is what I need. One question tho: Do I also get "null" or something that can tell me there was no key for that specific description?

Comment: return does not match List<string> - I think it is just a set of keys based upon descriptions matching

Comment: Yes, should we change the return type of the Lookup method? to what? Dictionary<string,string>?

Comment: If you want a dictionary then yes, but I read your question as wanting just the key - hence my answer :)

Comment: @kidshaw well yeah but then when it returns back to the code, I still need to know which description was for which key, right? so dictionary?

Comment: Dictionary would make sense then. It wasn't clear that you still wanted the description - put that one down to scope change ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a join statement:

```
return (from r in repo.Content.MyTable
         join d in des on r.Description equals d
         select r.Key).ToList();
```

If you want a dictionary:

```
return (from r in repo.Content.MyTable
         join d in des on r.Description equals d
         select r.Key, r.Description).ToDictionary(p=>p.Key, p=>p.Description);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private List<string> Lookup(List<string> des)
{
    var query = (from r in repo.Context.MyTable
        where des.Contains(r.Description)
        select r.Key);
    return query.ToList();
}
```

This is one query solution, this query will be materialize on this line:

```
return query.ToList();
```

Filtering will be made by sql.